# Portably safe to pass NULL/zero to dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, null, dynamic-cast

Out of habit for checking null pointers, I have sometimes written:

```
MyClass * c = someBasePtr ? dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(someBasePtr) : 0;
if (c) {...
```

In effect, checking for a null pointer before passing to dynamic cast, and also checking the return.

I then read in the MSDN documentation

> A null pointer value is converted to
>   the null pointer value of the
>   destination type by dynamic_cast.

It appears then that I could remove the ?: construct safely.  Is this C++ *portable*?

Such that the new code would be

```
MyClass * c = dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(someBasePtr);
if (c) {...
```

Of course presuming that *someBasePtr* is either null or valid, i.e. not *wild* pointing to garbage...

Answer (score 104, accepted):

§5.2.7/4:

> If the value of v is a null pointer
>   value in the pointer case, the result
>   is the null pointer value of type R.

So you don't have to check for a null pointer yourself. Same goes for operator delete, deleting a null pointer has no effect.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, you can use `dynamic_cast` on a null pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, check 5.2.7.4 in standard.